# Emberjs watching for variable changes passed from parent component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following code on child component to listen to changes

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Component.extend({

  coordinates: Ember.computed("mouse_x", "mouse_y", function () {
    let val = ` ${mouse_x},${mouse_y}`;
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  }),

  coords_change_observer: Ember.observer('coordinates', function () {
    console.log(this.coordinates);
  })
});
```

> The values **mouse_x** and **mouse_y** are set properly as i verified that from the view. I am passing that to this component from another component using

```
{{#application-properties mouse_x=mouse_x mouse_y=mouse_y}}
{{/application-properties}}
```

The basic goal being listening to changes on the variables passed through parent and process them. The issue being neither the `computed` nor the `observer` method is being invoked. Where am i going wrong with this ?

> Note that both of them are components and one of them being a child component inside another. Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you consuming coordinates anywhere? Ie, have you called "this.get('coordinates') or used `{{coordinates}}` in a template? In Ember, computed properties are lazily evaluated. So, until they're referenced, they're never executed.

Comment: Should be what @mistahenry said, so try to observe `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` directly.

Comment: I take it your child component is mutating `mouse_x` and `mouse_y`?  I strongly recommend not doing this, as it violates the Data Down/Actions Up philosophy: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/readers-questions-what-is-meant-by-the-term-data-down-actions-up/15311

You should instead have the child component send actions back up to the parent, and have the parent reset the values.  It will make your life so much easier.

Comment: @dwenzel exactly what you said and what @mistahenry called out about the lazy evaluation in emberjs. Both of those resolved my issue. Did learn that `computed` is evaluated lazy which is something new i came across

Answer (score 0):

Since Ember is quite efficient by only reusing parts of the DOM that are dynamic, I have found `addObserver` found [here](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/EmberObject) in the docs quite useful for a variety of items in my application that also aren't consumed in the component template.

```js
didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    // this is important b/c even though url may change, glimmer does not recognize this as a change and will not re-fire didInsertElement
    this.addObserver('media.url', this, '_setHref');
}
```

Also note, `@tracked` is the new way to track state change if you are able to take advantage.

https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/be351b059f08ac0fe709bc7697860d5064717a7f/text/0000-tracked-properties.md

https://www.pzuraq.com/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-3-tracked-properties/

https://glimmerjs.com/guides/tracked-properties